# How to properly implement next/link with SSR on next.js

Tags: reactjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, next.js

I have basically a next.js website with 3 pages.
Those are `Home`, `About` and `Admin`

`Home` and `About` are statically rendered and `Admin` uses `getServerSideProps`.
The reason behind this is, that I check within `getServerSideProps` for authentication via JWT.

The navigation between pages is with next/link with works without problems on the first two pages.
And also on the `Admin` page it works without problems in development environment `npm run dev` and `localhost`. Also when I do `npm run build` and `npm start` there are no problems.

When I deploy this via `npm run build` to AWS (with elasticbeanstalk) I can navigate between first two pages. But when I try to navigate to the 3rd page I receive `500 Internal Server Error.`

The logs on AWS show the following:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: ]
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: }
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: Error: Cannot find module 'sharp'
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: Require stack:
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/image-optimizer.js
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: Learn more: https://err.sh/next.js/install-sharp
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at imageOptimizer (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/image-optimizer.js:4:7)
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at async Router.execute (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/router.js:23:67)
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at async Server.run (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:66:1042)
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at async Server.handleRequest (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:34:1081) {
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: requireStack: [
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/image-optimizer.js',
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js',
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js',
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js',
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js',
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: ]
Feb  4 14:48:26 ip-172-31-23-92 web: }
Feb  4 14:48:29 ip-172-31-23-92 web: Query succeeded.
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: Error: Cannot find module 'next/Link'
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: Require stack:
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/require.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Object.biE2 (/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js:333:18)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at __webpack_require__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js:23:31)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Module.IT5z (/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js:152:13)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at __webpack_require__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js:23:31)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Object.2 (/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js:99:18)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at __webpack_require__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js:23:31) {
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: requireStack: [
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/require.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: ]
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: }
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: Error: Cannot find module 'next/Link'
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: Require stack:
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/require.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Object.biE2 (/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js:333:18)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at __webpack_require__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js:23:31)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Module.IT5z (/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js:152:13)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at __webpack_require__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js:23:31)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at Object.2 (/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js:99:18)
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: at __webpack_require__ (/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js:23:31) {
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: requireStack: [
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/.next/server/pages/admin.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/require.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js',
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: '/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: ]
Feb  4 14:48:32 ip-172-31-23-92 web: }
```

I only have vague idea why that could be. The [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) state, that next/link is only for client side routing, so maybe I cannot use it on a SSR page?
But if that is the case, why does it work in local environment?
And how do I fix it/ how do I implement routing with SSR (without using  tags).

If I leave the `<Link>` and next/link out and just navigate with `<a>`-tags, the error does not occure. So what is the reason behing it?

I also tried to wrap the  with `if(typeof window!== undefined` to make sure my code only gets executed on the client side.

Here is the (relevant) code for admin page:

```
import Link from "next/Link";
import styles from "../styles/menubar.module.css";
import Head from "next/head";
import auth from '../utils/auth';

export default function Admin() {

    if (typeof window !== undefined) {
        return (
            <>
                <Head>
                    <title>Admin</title>
                    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
                </Head>

                <div>

                    <div className={styles.nav}>
                        <Link href="/">
                            <a >
                                Home
                            </a>
                        </Link>
                        <p>|</p>
                        <Link href="/aboutproject">
                            <a >
                                About this project
                            </a>
                        </Link>
                        <p>|</p>
                        <Link href="/admin">
                            <a >
                                Admin
                            </a>
                        </Link>
                    </div>

                    <main className={`main ${style}`}>
                        <h1>Admin Page</h1>
                    </main>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }

    //}
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

    auth(context);

    return {
        props: {}, 
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is complaining about the typo in your `Link` import. `import Link from "next/Link"` should be `import Link from "next/link"` (lowercase L). As for the `sharp` error, you might want to have a look at the URL mentioned in the error: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/errors/install-sharp.md.

Comment: Seems like the error was caused by the capital `L`. Thanks for the hint. But why is that a downvote? The error did not occure on local environment and also not on deployed environment for the first two pages where I also had a capital `L`. So this behaviour does not seem to be logical or "trivial" at all